# right and left div css

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to make 2 divs in one line but there is a problem with that. i really don't know how to solve that problem.

```
<div class="wrapper">

<span class="left">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">ipad</a></li>
<li><a href="#">iphone</a></li>
<li><a href="#">mac</a></li>
<li><a href="#">ipod</a></li>
<li><a href="#">apple tv</a></li>
</ul>
</span>

<span class="right">
right content
</span>

</div>
```

and css is:

```
.wrapper{position:absolute;font-size:16px;height:15%;width:100%;}
.left{float:left;left:0;width:60%;}
.right{float:right;right:0;width:300px;}

ul {
list-style: none outside none;
}

li {
background-image: url(arrow.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: -1 .4em;
display: inline;
margin: 20px;
}
```

here you can see fiddled version: http://jsfiddle.net/5wquccee/

Comment: right content is one line upper.. problem is that.

Comment: Have you tried `ul{margin:0}`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/5wquccee/1/

Comment: oriol thanks man it fixed. i'm really newbie on coding stuff ;)

Comment: CSS is not *coding*. Also, please remove `right:0;` and `left:0;` as they are useless without `position: relative/absolute/fixed`

Answer (score 0):

use `float:left` instead of `float:right;`

```
.wrapper{position:absolute;font-size:16px;height:15%;width:100%;float:left;}
.left{float:left;width:60%;}
.right{float:left;width:30%;}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgd2ruw9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper{position:absolute;font-size:16px;height:15%;width:100%; }
.left{float:left;left:0;width:60%;}
.right{float:right;right:0;width:300px;}

ul {
list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

li {
background-image: url(arrow.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: -1 .4em;
display: inline;
margin: 0px 20px;
}
div{overflow: visible;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

<span class="left">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">ipad</a></li>
<li><a href="#">iphone</a></li>
<li><a href="#">mac</a></li>
<li><a href="#">ipod</a></li>
<li><a href="#">apple tv</a></li>
</ul>
</span>

<span class="right">
right content
</span>

</div>
```

try using this css

```
.wrapper{position:absolute;font-size:16px;height:15%;width:100%; }
.left{float:left;left:0;width:60%;}
.right{float:right;right:0;width:300px;}

ul {
list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

li {
background-image: url(arrow.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: -1 .4em;
display: inline;
margin: 0px 20px;
}
div{overflow: visible;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to the `span class="right"` a positional value, so that you can move it around as you like.
I gave it the attribute `position: relative;` so that you can move it around within the `.wrapper`.

Also I changed the `margin` attribute for your list to zero, so that both divs are inline.

This is what I changed:

```
.right{
    position: relative;
    right:0;
    width:300px;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none outside none;
}
```

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5wquccee/2/